# React newbie getting an error "Property 'blockStyleFn' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was trying to set styles for my codeblock and got an error from this part,

```
blockStyleFn={myBlockStyleFn}
```

It says "Property 'blockStyleFn' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'."
Below is the full code of TextEditor.tsx for my draftjs editor and customBlock.css which is located in the same folder. I don't understand why this specific property is not identified while others are working well under Editor. I guess I may have to specify the type of property somewhere. How can I fix this error?

> TextEditor.tsx

```
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { ContentBlock, ContentState, convertFromHTML, convertToRaw, EditorState } from "draft-js";
import draftToHtml from "draftjs-to-html";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
import "./customBlock.css";


    const TextEditor = ({ onChange, value } : any) => {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
    const [updated, setUpdated] = useState(false);
    
  
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!updated) {
        const defaultValue = value ? value : "";
        const blocksFromHtml = convertFromHTML(defaultValue);
        const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
          blocksFromHtml.contentBlocks,
          blocksFromHtml.entityMap
        );
        const newEditorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
        setEditorState(newEditorState);
      }
    }, [value]);
  
    const onEditorStateChange = (editorState : any) => {
      setUpdated(true);
      setEditorState(editorState);
      return onChange(draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())));
    };
  
    const toolbar = {
      options: ["inline", "blockType", "list"],
      inline: {
        inDropdown: false,
        options: ['bold', 'underline', 'italic']
      },
      blockType: {
        inDropdown: false,
        options: ["Normal", 'Blockquote', 'Code']
      },
      list: {
        inDropdown: false,
        options: ["unordered", "ordered"]
      },
    };     
    
    function myBlockStyleFn(contentBlock: ContentBlock) {
      const type = contentBlock.getType();
      if (type === 'code-block') {
        return 'customBlock';
      }
    }
    
    
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="editor" style={{maxHeight: "570px" , width:'100%' }}>
        <Typography sx={{fontSize: 20}}>
          <Editor  
            spellCheck
            editorState={editorState}
            onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
            toolbar={toolbar}
            editorStyle={{height: "500px" }} 
            blockStyleFn={myBlockStyleFn}             
          />
          </Typography>
        </div>
        
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };
  
  export default TextEditor;
```

> customBlock.css

```
.customBlock {
    color: #999;
    font-family: 'Hoefler Text', Georgia, serif;
    display:block;
  }
```

Comment: looks like a problem with function myBlockStyleFn it will only return if condition is true (type === 'code-block'). Also use this with function i.e. blockStyleFn={this.myBlockStyleFn}

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to be working @SainPradeep